# Front-end processes before back-end?

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, frontend, backend

I noticed on most modern web apps that front-end processing (like in the case of pushing a button) usually occurs before back-end processing, and if the back-end process fails, it throws some kind of exception which returns the front-end to its previous state. What is this technique/feature called and where can I learn more about it? Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript + Ajax = No Page reloading (if developer want that) . 
There are many JavaScript frameworks and other things as Angular JS which can do many things without refreshing the browser. 
How ever the real DATA work is proceeded always in the backend !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about ajax technology, full meaning is **asynchronous JavaScript and XML**. Ajax is a pure javascript technique. If you learn jQuery, Ajax will be easy for you. Google 'ajax' and you will find a lot of documentation on ajax.